# HCMOS drivers impedance table

Tags: termination

I wonder, is there a table somewhere where I can find out impedance of drivers of various HCMOS series?

I am specifically interested in AC, ACT, LVC and HC series. I guess input impedance is very high for all CMOS-based series, so I am interested in drivers impedance only.

I need that to properly terminate long trances, and I guess different series would require a bit different termination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TI do some good app notes on their logic families, it's just a matter of finding the right one :-)
I have one here on my computer called "[Designing with Logic - SDYA009C](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/sdya009c/sdya009c.pdf)" containing the table shown below. It's a little old now (1997) but I'm pretty sure there will be a similar app note for the newer chips. Here is a [TI page](http://focus.ti.com/logic/docs/techdocs.tsp?sectionId=452&tabId=1989&viewType=mostuseful&rootFamilyId=1&familyId=1&docCategoryId=2&docCategoryId=1&docCategoryId=6&docCategoryId=10&docCategoryId=11&docCategoryId=4&docCategoryId=3&docCategoryId=5) with tons of logic related documents.
The [HCMOS design guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scla007a/scla007a.pdf) and [Input/Output characteristics](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza008/szza008.pdf) might be of use.

[image: 7400_table]